# How to reference a specific cell in a formula based on the contents of two other cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to do a simple calculation where I multiply the contents of one cell by the contents of another. I have one table with 52 rows, and one with 9000. I want to multiply A value in the first table by a certain value in the second table based on two other values in the first table.

The three values in the first table are N, Week, and Hour. The Rows in the second table are weeks 1-53 and the columns are hour 1-24. I want to create a formula that says "if Hour is 3 and Week is 2 in table 1, multiply Count by the value denoted by column 3 and row 2 in table 2."

I've tried creating a named range with the Column headers being "Hour_1...Hour24" and the Row headers being "Week_1...Week_52". I then tried using the formula =Count*INDEX(Week_(A2),B2), where A2 is the week # in table 1 and B2 is the hour # in table 1. The main problem I'm encountering with this approach is that excel does not recognize Week_(A2) as a row. You would think that if A2=3, the system would recognize Week_(A2) as Week_3, but it doesn't. Any advice or ideas?

Comment: Some sample data or a screenshot would make this question easier to answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question that why your **INDEX** formula is not working, you need to use one of the following instead:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("Week_"&A2),,B2)
```

or

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("Hour_"&B2),A2)
```

If you put **WEEK_(A2)** into a single cell, it will return an error **#NAME?**, which means Excel cannot recognize the referenced value hence you cannot use it in calculation.

If you want to refer to the row named **Week_2**, you need to use **INDIRECT** function such as `{=INDIRECT("Week_"&(A2))}` which shall return a range of values stored in that row. Please note it is an **array formula** so if you want to put in a cell to test the outcome, you need to press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to make it work. It will return the first value of the range in a single cell, but if you highlight the formula in the formula bar and press **F9**, you will be able to see the full range of values it represents.

When using **INDEX**, you can either

1) refer to a row, and locate a value within that row by providing the column position, or

2) refer to a column, and locate a value within that column by providing the row position; or

3) refer to a continuous range of data such as a table, and you can locate a value within that range by providing the row and column position; or

4) refer to a non-continuous range of data such as `(A2:A5,B4:B7)`, and you can locate one area of data by providing the area number **(this is not relevant to your case)**

The first three points explained why both of the above INDEX formula will find the value you want in Table 2, and also lead to a simpler solution below:

```
=INDEX(Table2,A2,B2+1)
```

You do not even need to name each column and row in Table 2 but simply refer to **Table2** in your INDEX formula to get the value you want given that you know the column (Hour) and row (Week) position already.

I am not too sure what value is behind the `Count` in your original formula, but I think it is the INDEX part that you are having problem with, and I presume you want to multiply the corresponding value in **N** column with the number you find in Table 2. You can refer to my following screen-shot for more clarifications.

[image: INDEX Example]

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)